# Get number from Text only with currency Java

Tags: java, regex, string, numbers

I want get number from String which have currency. 
For example:

```
String text = "player number 8 have a nice day. the price is 1 000 $ or you have to pay 2000$.";
```

So the output i want:

```
1000,2000
```

I use this:

```
String tmp = text.replaceAll("[^0-9]+", " ");
List<String> digitsList = Arrays.asList(tmp.trim().split(" "));
```

But my output is:

```
8,000,2000
```

Is any idea to get number from text if number is written like this: 1 000, 30 000.

And any way to get number only with currency ?

Comment: Can you please be more specific on your question?  We don't do "gimme teh codez" here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex `(([0-9]+\s?)+)\$` with pattern like this, which mean one or more degit can be followed by a space and all that end with curency sign `$`:

```
String text = "player number 8 have a nice day. the price is 1 000 $ or you have to pay 2000$.";
String regex = "(([0-9]+\\s?)+)\\$";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

while (matcher.find()) {                                                
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

result

```
1 000
2000
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sREGmm/1)

---

**Edit**

> What i have to write in regex when i have two currency? 1000$ and
>   1000EUR

In this case you can use this regex instead `(([0-9]+\s?)+)(\$|EUR)` which can match both `$` sign and `EUR`

```
String regex = "(([0-9]+\\s?)+)(\\$|EUR)";
```

[regex demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/sREGmm/2)

---

**Edit2**

> I tested this and i find another trap. When i have **2000,00 $ and 1
>   000,00 EUR i get 00,00**. So what i have to add to regex that give me
>   **2000,1000**?
>
> So final example: I have : **1000$ and 5 000 EUR and 2 000 , 00 $ and
>   3000,00 EUR** And output should be: **1000,5000,2000,3000**, any regex for
>   this?

In this case you can use this regex `(([0-9]+[\s,]*)+)(\$|EUR)` which can allow space and comma between numbers, then when you get the result you can replace all non degit with empty like this :

```
String text = "1000$ and 5 000 EUR and 2 000 , 00 $ and 3000,00 EUR";
//1000,5000,2000,3000
String regex = "(([0-9]+[\\s,]*)+)(\\$|EUR)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1).replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""));
    //                                              ^^^^^^--------to get only the degits
}
```

**Output**

```
1000
5000
200000
300000
```

[regex demo 3](https://regex101.com/r/sREGmm/3)

Comment: Your comeback :)

Comment: What i have to write in regex when i have two currency? `1000$ and 1000EUR` ?

Comment: @Alcwak you have to use this regex in this case `(([0-9]+\\s?)+)(\\$|EUR)` hope this can help you :)

Comment: Thank you. I tested this and i find another trap. When i have `2000,00 $ and 1 000,00 EUR` i get `00,00`. So what i have to add to regex that give me `2000,1000`?

Comment: So final example: I have : `1000$ and 5 000 EUR and 2 000 , 00 $ and 3000,00 EUR` And output should be: `1000,5000,2000,3000`, any regex for this?

Comment: yes @Alcwak you can check my edit hope this can help you :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150582/discussion-between-alcwak-and-ycf-l).

Comment: @Alcwak sorry i can't use chat room in my network if you have any question you can use comments :)

Comment: Thanks for helping, now it works perfect.
I have another question, maybye you know answer, since i'm looking for another regex: I have: `"The price is 1 000$. You have to pay 1400 EUR, and you have to pay extra 2000$". `What i want? I want price, but if before price is word "pay" or "pay extra" then i must reject this price. I have regex which you wrote that give me price, so it is great, but i think that i need another? or modify your regex that reject some price if before price is specjal word. Output of my example should be: `1000`

Comment: @Alcwak it can be better if you create a new question instead explain every thing, just to make Q&A more helpful for other, when you create it inform me ok :)

Comment: @YCF_L okey,this is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45415457/reject-price-before-special-word-regex-java