# reject price before specific word, regex java

Tags: java, regex

I have: `"The price is 1 000$ another pice 34 000 , 00 EUR. You have to pay 1400 EUR, and you have to pay extra 2000$"`. What i want? I want price, but if before price is word "pay" or "pay extra" then i must reject this price. I have regex  that give me price, so it is great, but i think that i need another? or modify  regex that reject some price if before price is specific word. Output of my example should be: `1000,34000`
My code:

```
String regex = "(([0-9]+[\\s,.]*)+)(\\$|EUR)";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
while (matcher.find()) {
            price = matcher.group();
if (price.contains(",")) {
            price = price.substring(0, price.indexOf(","));
        }
        price = price.replaceAll("\\s", "").replaceAll("[^0-9]+", "");
        if (price.contains(",")) {
            price = price.replaceAll("\\,", "");
        } else {
            price = price.replaceAll("\\.", "");
        }
```

It give me:

```
1000,34000,1400,2000
```

But I want only: `1000,34000` I must reject these prices that are after word "pay" and "pay extra".
edit: "." is for price like this 1 000. 00

Comment: See http://ideone.com/0O3Dp0. What are `.` for in the pattern?

Comment: You can use something of the likes `^(price\s(extra\s)?)`

Comment: i think the solution of @WiktorStribiżew can help you Alcwak ;)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `.` is for price like 2 000 . 00. What i have to add to your regex when i want add more words that before i reject price? Now i can reject words: `"price", "extra"` but when i want more like: `"price","extra","more extra", "something else"`. What i have to add?

Comment: Add more alternatives into Group 1. You may use it like `\\b(price|extra|more extra|something else)?\\b\\s*`. See [**this Java demo**](http://ideone.com/XFZdHT).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand you have strings where decimal separator is a comma, and dots are digit grouping symbol.

You may match the `pay` or `pay extra` words as an optional capturing group `(\\bpay(?:\\s+extra)?\\s*)?` and check if the group matched. If it did, the match should be discarded, else, grab the number and remove `,` and the digits after it. Then, just remove all non-digit symbols.

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/0O3Dp0):

```
String text = "The price is 1 000$ another pice 34 000 , 00 EUR. You have to pay 1400 EUR, and you have to pay extra 2000$";
String regex = "(\\bpay(?:\\s+extra)?\\s*)?(\\d[\\d\\s,.]*)(?:\\$|EUR)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(text);
List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
while (m.find()) {
    if (m.group(1) == null) {
        res.add(m.group(2).replaceAll(",\\s*\\d+|\\D", ""));
    }
}
System.out.println(res);
// => [1000, 34000]
```

**Pattern details**:

- `(\\bpay(?:\\s+extra)?\\s*)?` - an optional capturing group matching a whole word `pay` or `pay extra` (with any 1+ whitespaces in between) and then 0+ whitespaces (when the group does not match, the `matcher.group(1)` is *null*)
- `(\\d[\\d\\s,.]*)` - Group 2: a digit and then 0+ digits, whitespaces, `,` or/and `.` symbols
- `(?:\\$|EUR)` - a non-capturing group matching either a `$` symbol or `EUR` substring.

The `,\\s*\\d+|\\D` pattern matches `,`, 0+ whitespaces and 1+ digits or any non-digit symbol.

**NOTE**: If you can have *both* `.` and `,` as a *decimal separator*, in the last regex, replace `,` with `[,.]`. See [this Java demo](http://ideone.com/XFZdHT).

Comment: Can you write me a final example with words before: `"price","extra","more extra", "something else`. I try add this: `\\b(price|extra|more extra|something else)?\\b\\s*` but i don't know exacly where i must add it in regex and what i have to remove.

Comment: See http://ideone.com/tld8m5. These alternations should be written as `\b(var1|var2|varN)\b\s*`. I just shorten `pay` and `pay extra` into a single branch by using a [*non-capturing* optional group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471) to make the pattern more efficient. You should follow the same to keep it robust. To make a non-capturing group optional just add `?` after it (so that it looks like `(?:...)?`)

Answer (score 1):

I would sugegst the following method.

First I would get rid of whitespaces since they do not introduce any valuable information we need to take into account when parse.

Then I would substitute the decimal separator so that it is more common.

Now let me show in the code:

```
String parsePrices(String input){

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    String preprocessedInput = input.
            replaceAll("\\s", "").
            replaceAll("(\\d)(\\,)(\\d)", "$1\\.$3");

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<!pay|payextra)((?<=[^\\d])\\d+\\.?\\d+)(\\$|EUR)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(preprocessedInput);

    while(m.find()){
        result.append(String.format("%.0f", Double.parseDouble(m.group(1)))).append(",");
    }

    return result.toString().substring(0, result.length()-1);
}
```

Where:

- first `replaceAll()` removes teh whitespaces
- second `replaceAll()` changes decimal separator
- regular expression uses `negative-look-behind` approach to exculde the proces which follow either pay or payextra
- `String.format("%.0f", Double.parseDouble(m.group(1)))` allows you to tune how precise you would like your prices be.